# template class derived from `const` specialized version

Tags: c++

I've stumbled upon this code (simplified version here):

```
    template<typename T>
    class SmartPtr;

    template<typename T>
    struct SmartPtr<const T>
    {
        const T& operator*() const { return *_ptr; }
        const T* operator->() const { return _ptr; }
        const T* _ptr;
        // more member data and functions here
        // ...
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct SmartPtr : public SmartPtr<const T>
    {
        T& operator*() const { return *const_cast<T*>(_ptr); }
        T* operator->() const { return const_cast<T*>(_ptr); }
    };
```

It's the first time I see a template class derived like this. Can anyone help me understand what one can achieve using this? To me it seems the general version behaves the same as the specialization if instantiated with a `const T` and the specialization is not necessary. Am I missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't non-const version have non-const methods instead (`T& operator*();`)?

Comment: Can you also add the pointer member variables and how the functions are actually defined?

Comment: @MarcStevens I added the implementation. I can't add too much info about it and I hope the part that is not in the question is not containing relevant info

Comment: @Mircae: Now it's more clear how the base class is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general behaviour of `SmartPtr<T>` and `SmartPtr<const T>` is indeed identical and no specialization would have been needed simply to handle const and non-const versions of T.

However, the answer to your question lies in that this construction allows for implicit conversion from `SmartPtr<T>` to `SmartPtr<const T>`.

For instance, a function defined for `SmartPtr<const foo>` can be called with a `SmartPtr<foo>` as well, and thus you don't need two overloads to handle both cases:

```
void HandleFoo(SmartPtr<foo> ptr);
void HandleConstFoo(SmartPtr<const foo> ptr);
void dotask()
{
    SmartPtr<foo> fooptr = new foo ...;
    ...
    HandleFoo(fooptr);
    HandleConstFoo(fooptr); // implicit conversion
}
```

Simply defining a single class `SmartPtr<T>` does not allow for implicit conversion from `SmartPtr<T>` to `SmartPtr<const T>`.

For implicit conversion between *different* types you would normally add extra member functions, but in this case for the same class from non-const to const you would run into problems.
A specialization with a `const T` base class is one of the ways to avoid those problems.

Comment: To illustrate `void Foo(SmartPtr<const Quux>& quux);` free standing function can take a `SmartPtr<Quux> q; Foo(q);` argument and it will fulfill the quux parameter.

Answer (score 4):

> To me it seems the general version behaves the same as the specialization if instantiated with a `const T`

If instantiated with a `const T`, the primary template version isn't used at all. The specialization will be used.

If instantiated with a **non-const** `T`, then the primary simply reuses the code from the specialization, by tweaking the return types to make sense for a pointer to a non-const piece of data.

It's also a way to get "expected" behavior between the `SmartPtr` specializations (to behave as standard raw pointers do with regard to qualification conversions). We can add converting constructors of course but not all cases are covered with this approach. Consider this

```
template<class U>
void frombulate(SmartPtr<const U>) {
}
```

Can we call `frombulate` with a `SmartPtr<int>`? In this implementation [we can](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rEWyGr98mLwfIL0E) (because derived-to-base conversions are allowed in template argument deduction). But a converting constructor [would not allow us that](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3mW6zniYJb0qdrgx), since general conversions in template argument deduction may not be considered.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough with `To me it seems the general version behaves the same as the specialization if instantiated with a const T`. What I meant is that the general version behaves exactly as the specialization if the specialization didn't exist and the general version was instantiated with `const T`

Comment: @MirceaIspas - Only in isolation. And you must bear in mind that this technique doesn't prevent you from changing the behavior in more profound ways.

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm asking myself why the standard library `shared_ptr` doesn't allow this conversion

Comment: @MirceaIspas - Can't answer that, I'm afraid.